# Which tool can I use to encrypt bacpac file using azure key vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, encryption-symmetric, sqlpackage, bacpac

I exported my azure SQL Managed instance to a Bacpac file using SQLPackage, Now I want to store it on a azure file storage. Before I want to copy the bacpac to the file storage, I want to encrypt it using a Secret from Azure key vault. SQLPackage does not have any encryption functionality, does anyone know a good tool I can use to encrypt the bacpac file before copying to the file storage? Preferably a tool I can call in my ps1 (powershell) script. I want to use the same tool to decrypt the bacpac file again once downloaded from the file storage.

Answer (score 0):

The official approach is to use [client-side encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault). However, there is no existing tools. You may write a program to upload the encrypted content and download the decrypted content.

Here are two official client=side encryption samples:

1. .NET sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-client-side-encryption
2. Java sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-java-client-side-encryption